# How to get the value of selected checkbox with specific name using jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

i have this check box with different name but all the name start with checkUser

```
<input type="checkbox" value="60176694447" name="checkUser52106">
<input type="checkbox" value="60176694448" name="checkUser52107">
<input type="checkbox" value="60176694449" name="checkUser52108">
```

[A quick google bring me this function from sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/javascript-15/get-value-checkbox-checked-jquery-583619.html)

```
$(function(){
$('#btnClick').click(function(){
var val = [];
$(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
  val[i] = $(this).val();
});
});
});
```

Right now i want to get all the value of selected checkbox with name start with checkUser. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [attribute startsWith selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$(':checkbox[name^="checkUser"]:checked').each(function(i){
    val[i] = $(this).val();
});
```

You can use [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) instead for a shorter solution:

```
var val = $(':checkbox[name^="checkUser"]:checked').map(function(){
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSS3 type selector like this

```
$('input[name=~"checkUser"]:checked').each( function(idx) {
    val[idx] = $(this).val();
});
```

---

Edit: oh, same exact answer as above :P